# Polynomial Multiplication using structures

Tags: c, structure

I have made a program for performing polynomial multiplication using structure format
now the problem here is i think that my logic is right ,even though i know this method is heavy on time complexity ,this is the best i could have created ,but here the first 2 polynomials are displayed perfectly ,but there no output for the multiply array ,is it problem with the deallocation of memory or something else ,pls help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct poly {
    int coeff;
    int expo;
} new;

new *poly1, *poly2, *q;
int u = 0, k = 0;

void create(new *poly, int n);
void add(new *y, new *t, int n, int m);
void multiply(int n, int m);

void create(new *poly, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the coeff and the expo of the polynomial:");
        scanf("%d%d", &poly[i].coeff, &poly[i].expo);
    }
}

void add(new *y, new *t, int n, int m) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m) {
        if (y[i].expo > t[j].expo) {
            q[k].coeff = y[i].coeff;
            q[k++].expo = y[i++].expo;
            u++;
        } else {
            if (y[i].expo < t[j].expo) {
                q[k].coeff = t[j].coeff;
                q[k++].expo = t[j++].expo;
                u++;
            } else {
                q[k].coeff = t[j].coeff * (y[i].expo);
                q[k++].expo = t[j++].expo + y[i++].expo;
                u++;
            }
        }
    }

    while (i < n) {
        q[k].coeff = y[i].coeff;
        q[k++].expo = y[i++].expo;
        u++;
    }

    while (j < m) {
        q[k].coeff = t[j].coeff;
        q[k++].expo = t[j++].expo;
        u++;
    }
}

void multiply(int n, int m) {
    int i = 0;
    new y[m * n];

    for (int p = 0; p < m * n; p++) {
        y[p].coeff = 0;
        y[p].expo = 0;
    }

    while (i < n) {
        new *t = (new *)malloc(sizeof(new) * m);
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m) {
            t[j].expo = poly1[i].expo + poly2[j].expo;
            t[j].coeff = poly1[i].coeff * poly2[j].coeff;
            j++;
        }
        add(y, t, n, m);
        i++;
    }
}

void display(new *poly, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", poly[i].coeff, poly[i].expo);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter the number of term of polynomial one :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the number of terms of polynomial two");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    poly1 = (new *)malloc(sizeof(new) * n);
    poly2 = (new *)malloc(sizeof(new) * m);
    q = (new *)malloc(sizeof(new) * n * m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
        q[i].coeff = 0;
        [i].expo = 0;
    }
    
    create(poly1, n);
    create(poly2, m);
    display(poly1, n);
    display(poly2, m);
    new *y = q;
    display(y, u);
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags. C++ is not C and your code wouldn't compile as C++ (because `new` is a keyword here).

Comment: Plenty of bad habits in that code. Why are you naming the type-alias `new`? How does that name describe what the structure is and what it does? And why all the global variables? Why the nondescript `n` and `m` for the polynomial sizes? Also in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And  why the temporary variable `y` (again with the bad naming)? Why can't you pass `q` itself to the `display` function?

Comment: Oh, and you should really make sure that you copy-paste the correct [mre]. The code you show won't build.

Comment: As for ways to solve problems like this, please learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.